# Postman Update collections when Define API changes

Tags: postman

Now i am using postman Version 7.34.0.

I imported swagger 2.0 api and create collection, create mock server and mock example data for the api request.

Everything works well.

But when i found that our api changes, i update the API in the postman. But there is no way to update collection.

I checked this [Webinar tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aolgf6tQaqQ&t=1563s) at time of 25:35, adding the parameters in the header, then it demo how to update to collection.

But for my case, i tested with our swagger api changes or create a new yaml of openapi 3.0 api, made the changes in query param or add/remove the request. But there is nowhere I can update collection.

I only saw to 'Generate Collection' button, i don't want to generate a new collection, because there can be lots of api I already added the example response data, so I don't want to generate new collection for the api changes, I just want to update the existing collection and later i can manually modify the example response data.

But now I can only manually change the collection for the api changes, not very convenient to use. I also see the posting api to [get and update collection with body](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/631643/JsLs/#8ca888b7-ef54-f3b4-312f-3f3e2e2cf04e). But it is more difficult to use.

Is there any button click to update collection anywhere else?

Thanks a lot.